# What's an SVG image rendered as PNG?

Tags: svg

There's an svg image of Alabama's state flag @ [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Flag_of_Alabama.svg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aFlag_of_Alabama.svg)

The caption says "This image rendered as PNG in other sizes." I downloaded the 1,000-pixel size @
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5c/Flag_of_Alabama.svg/1000px-Flag_of_Alabama.svg.png but it won't display on my web page. I opened it in Photoshop, copied it into a new window and saved it with a new file name, but it still doesn't display.

So I guess I was wrong when I thought "rendered as a PNG" means an image is a png. It's actually a SVG...with a .png extension?

Anyway, I just wondered what's going on here and what I need to do to download such images as pngs. Or is the only solution to take a screenshot?

Comment: Displaying fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/9u5X2/ No point in using a PNG here though, JPG will have the same quality and will reduce the file size(thus saving you bandwidth).

Comment: Hmmmm...I thought jogs were a BIGGER file size? Maybe I should convert all the state flag images I downloaded to jogs. Is there a way to batch process them, or do I have to open and change them one at a time? (Or should I start a different discussion for that question?)

Comment: I think I found the answer to my second question here: http://osxdaily.com/2010/01/24/convert-images-in-mac-os-x-jpg-to-gif-psd-to-jpg-gif-to-jpg-bmp-to-jpg-png-to-pdf-and-more/

Comment: I just converted one to a .jpg, and the file size is four or five times bigger.

Comment: GIF and PNG are lossless whereas JPG is lossy, so you must be doing something wrong if you're getting a larger image when converting to JPG. PNGs are typically used when you want transparency within the image.

Comment: You're right; I converted my jpg back to png, and it's HUGE. My original png was only about 8 K, but it won't display, so there must be something wrong with it. I guess I'll have to settle for a 40K jpg. That's actually not so big, especially considering the size of these images. Thx.

Comment: No problem, there are several methods of batch conversion from PNG to JPG, "Bulk Image Converter" is the one I use. Hope that helps!

Comment: First commenter is wrong.  JPEG images are intended for photographic images.  Using JPEG for these sort of images is not generally a great idea.

Answer (score 1):

The PNG file you linked to (the ".png" link) is not an SVG. It is definitely a PNG.

I don't know why it isn't displaying for you, but it has nothing to do with SVG.

Answer (score 0):

To get the image as .svg just copy the source of the page (of the image) to an editor. Now save it as an .svg image

Comment: Thanks, but that's not my goal. I want to use an extension that can be automatically resized to display in mobile devices as well as regular web pages. As I understand, sag images can't do that.